# Sphinx delta index example in documentation doesn't seem correct

Tags: sphinx

[The Sphinx documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates) says to use a delta index like this:

```
# in MySQL
CREATE TABLE sph_counter
(
    counter_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    max_doc_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

# in sphinx.conf
source main
{
    # ...
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query_pre = REPLACE INTO sph_counter SELECT 1, MAX(id) FROM documents
    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
        WHERE id<=( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}

source delta : main
{
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query = SELECT id, title, body FROM documents \
        WHERE id>( SELECT max_doc_id FROM sph_counter WHERE counter_id=1 )
}

index main
{
    source = main
    path = /path/to/main
    # ... all the other settings
}

# note how all other settings are copied from main,
# but source and path are overridden (they MUST be)
index delta : main
{
    source = delta
    path = /path/to/delta
}
```

Why isn't `max_doc_id` updated after the delta index is run?

Unless I'm missing something, whenever the delta index is run using the above configuration, it's going to be re-indexing the same records over and over again until the main index is run.

This isn't a problem if the main index is run fairly often, but (as an extreme example) if the main index is never run again, then the delta index will essentially have the same problem as a non-delta index, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is correct, every time you rebuild the indexer, it needs to include ALL the records that at not in the MAIN.

So if the id was updated by the delta, records would disappear. (ie not in the main, and wouldnt be in the delta, next time its rebuilt)

Building indexes is an all or nothing endevour. Can't just run a SQL query to get the new records that attached to the end of the index.

... this is the reason for the main+delta scheme in the first place. So you dont have to index ALL records every time. The majority lives in teh MAIN, which just some in the DELTA, so the duplication isnt too bad.

---

Yes, you would update the main from time to time too. Perhaps daily or weekly - depending no the number of documents.

---

Because people dont like this scheme, is the main reasons for the development of the RT indexes, where you dont need to manage multiple indexes, you just interact with one index. (sphinx under the hood still maintains seperate indexes, so it doesnt have to update *everything* every time add/remove a document)